# Menu gone, all buttons gone

Tags: routes

My customer is using the "smokers" theme with Drupal 6.

Now we are observing a very strange behavior:

1. The menu bar that used to be on left side on the screen "disappeared", or more correct it is still existing on the left but out of the visible range.
2. After switching my page into maintanence mode and setting "Rebuild theme registry on every page." as it is stated in the upgrading information for the smokers theme all buttons have disappeared. They are invisible and it seems that I even cannot find the in the html source that is displayed in my browser.

So how can I fix these probs? Switching to a different theme could do the trick but this is not possible without buttons. `drush` is not installed on my server.

Can anybody help?

Cheers

Chris

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for smokers theme. As Help Center states, bugreports belongs to [appropriate issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/smokers) or customer service, not here.

Comment: @Molot: This is not a bug report. It is question how to get off this situation. I don't mind the possible theme bug and am willing to switch to another theme. But how???

Comment: This is a question how to get off a bug, isn't it? Anyway, Help Center forbids generally "Issues found in existing modules/themes". Changing themes can be done at http://example.com/admin/build/themes. Alternatively you can install Drush. Or revert your page from backup.

Comment: I cannot change a theme because I lack a confirmastion button in modules/themes :p
I cannot install drush on this dedicated server. And there is no backup that is old enough. :(
This is the reason why I posted this question!